# From ajaxcomplete to php variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating a list of users favourite items.

The users have an input field and when he press 'Search', it will show a list in `<div class="item-data"></div>`. This list will show the items matched with the keyword that was entered.

If the user finds an item it can be added to a list. I have figured out this bit and you can see it in my code below.

The only thing I can´t figure out is:
How to save the chosen items, that are in the `added_items` list, into a php variable to save them into a mysql table.

**index.php**

```
<div class="search_engine">
    <ul id="added_items" class="list-inline">
        <li>12 (itemid)</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item" name="item" placeholder="Enter item">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="send_button" id="get_item" >Search</button>
    <div class="item-data"></div>
</div>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
$keywords = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,trim($_POST['item']));
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item = '{$keywords}' ORDER BY item ASC");

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) === 0){
    echo "<h3>No items found</h3>";
} else {

    echo "<h3>Items (".mysqli_num_rows($query).")</h3>"; 
    echo '<ul id="items_list">';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo '<a id="'.$row['itemid'].'" href="#"> '.$row['item'].'</a></li>';
    }

    echo "</ul>";
} 
?>
```

**jquery.js**

```
<script>
function searching_for_items(){
    $('#item').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
            $('#get_item').click();//Trigger search button click event
        }
    }); 
    $('#get_item').on('click',function(){
        var name = $('#item').val();     

        if(name != ''){
            $.post('ajax.php', {item: name}, function(data){
                $('.item-data').html(data);
            });   
        }

    });
    // e.preventDefault();
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#items_list").children('li').click(function() {
        var rssId = $(this).children('a').attr('id');              
        $("#added_items").append("<li>" + rssId + "</li>");
    });
});
</script>
```

Hopefully someone understand what I want to do and I thank in advance for the help.

Comment: Use `SELECT * FROM items WHERE item LIKE '%keywords%' ORDER BY item ASC`

Comment: that does not solve my problem

Comment: That's why its in the comments...

Comment: Add more details to your question. Its not 100% clear what you are looking for. Also your posted code is messy

Comment: and you don't have a problem, but you have a challenge ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of the choosen items

```
var items = [];
items.push(rssId);
```

And later send this array with an ajax post, and put it in a database

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {items:items},
   url: "save_items.php",
   success: function(data){
     $('#result').html(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ramon, this works but it breaks when a user chooses more than one item. It shows only the clicked item. How can change it so every click is added to array.

Comment: Put the var items[] not in the click function. This will reset the array

Comment: But put it above the function

Comment: I still can´t make it to work. The odd thing is that if I check it through the console it works, but when passing to php it crashes. This is what I have entered in my save_items.php : `<div id="results">
<?php     @$src = $_POST['items']; 
         echo $src; 
?>
</div>`. The error I get is: **Notice: Array to string conversion**

Comment: I have solved it. I added a new variable to convert it string and it works. Thanks Ramon for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you out